# How to send push-notifications from java-server?

Tags: java, push-notification

I have apps on Android & iOS, & I need to send push-notifications to them from Java-server.

Please tell me, where can I find guides how to do this? I'm looking GCM & APN for Android.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google/Apple Push Notification Service (APNS/GCM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20685560/google-apple-push-notification-service-apns-gcm)

Answer (score 0):

https://firebase.google.com/

That is what I use for project and I am satisfied with it.

You have all needed tutorials and docs to start working with it.

Overview:

firebase provides You with Admin SDK wich helps You build Data and Notification messages and send it to firebase, firebase then sends it to either iOS or Android if You send it to specific client or to both if You send it to some created topic.
It also have easy to use Android, iOS, JavaScript libs to handle it on client-side.
ofc to get this work with Your server Client must generate notification token from provided google api and send it to Your server to store in DB.

there are some restriction though with push notifications 2kb if I remember correctly and 4kb for data messages keep it in mind when you create your communication architecture :)